# PyQt5: Reloading gif in Qmovie

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

How would I go about re-loading a new animated gif file in PyQt5?

What I want to do:

1. load test.gif
2. play test.gif
3. overwrite the original test.gif file with another arbitrary animated gif
4. have Qmovie reload the gif when the button is clicked
5. display the new gif

Here is the basic code I have set up to attempt this, however clicking the button to refresh does not work:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QByteArray, QSettings, QTimer, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QAction, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie

class GifPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.movie = QMovie("test.gif", QByteArray(), self)
        size = self.movie.scaledSize()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, size.width(), size.height())
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.movie_screen = QLabel()
        self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.movie.loopCount()

        button = QPushButton('refresh gif', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(10,10)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        print("done")     

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = GifPlayer("update this gif")
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You have to create another movie, and then call start()

Comment: I will be updating this every 5 minutes, will I have to keep creating another movie ever 5 minutes?

Comment: Yes, why do you want to look for another magical way?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a fundamentally easy fix. The error was trying to just refresh the movie_screen and not the movie itself. One just has to set the QMovie file again, have the movie_screen re-show it, and start the movie. Here is the corrected code:

```
gifFile = "test.gif"
class GifPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, gifFile, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.movie = QMovie(gifFile, QByteArray(), self)
        size = self.movie.scaledSize()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, size.width(), size.height())
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.movie_screen = QLabel()
        self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.movie.loopCount()

        button = QPushButton('refresh gif', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(10,10)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.movie = QMovie(gifFile,QByteArray(), self)
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = GifPlayer("update this gif", gifFile)
    player.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The on_click method was primarily what needed to be changed.